# there is mistake somewhere,i can't find it. code is work but it s wrong result. i want to fix but i don't know where is it. pls help me

Tags: c

there is mistake somewhere,i can't find it. code is work but it s wrong result. i want to fix but i don't know where is it. pls help me

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int elemansayisi;   //size
    printf("Eleman sayisini giriniz : ");
    scanf("%d", &elemansayisi); //size
    printf("\n");
    int dizi[elemansayisi], i, j; //array
    int enBuyuk = dizi[0]; //first biggest element 
    for (i = 0; i < elemansayisi; i++) {
        printf("Dizinin  elemanlanrini giriniz : "); //getting array from user
        scanf("%d", &dizi[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < elemansayisi; i++) {

        printf("dizinin %d. elemani: %d\n", i, dizi[i]);  //print array 
        printf("\n");

    }

    for (j = 0; j <= elemansayisi; j++) {

        if (enBuyuk <= dizi[j])  //find biggest element in array

            enBuyuk = dizi[j];

    }

    printf("En buyuk deger : %d", enBuyuk);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please indicate what you are trying to accomplish, and what the code currently does. If it gives an error message, what is it?

Comment: @CTHall:  He was pretty clear that he got the wrong result (no error message), and the intention of the code is quite well commented and easy to follow (even with the non-english variable names).  IMHO: this question is *above average* for this site!

Comment: Try to explain your code

Comment: when the code has a runtime problem, as this question indicates, then post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: OT: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding: ` scanf("%d", &elemansayisi); //size`  to be considered successful, in this case, the returned value must be 1.  Any other returned value indicates an error.  Should also validate `elemansayisi` to assure it is >0 and less than some max number.  I.E. never trust the user to do the right thing

Comment: you really need to learn how to use a debugger and how to debug your own programs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sets `enBuyuk` to a value that is undefined!

```
int enBuyuk = dizi[0]; //first biggest element
```

Instead, move this line to just above your for-loop.

---

```
for (j = 0; j <= elemansayisi; j++) {
```

This should be strictly less than (remove the `=` sign)

```
int enBuyuk = dizi[0]; // Move line here
for (j = 0; j < elemansayisi; j++) {
```